# runtime polymorphism and dynamic_cast need clarification

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

Might answered some where else, but could not found right phrase to ask

so hear it goes.

I have base class `A`, with child `B` and `C`; (completely for training purpose)

```
#include <iostream>

class A 
{ 
    public: 
        virtual void print () { std::cout<< "A::print()" << std::endl; } 
}; 

class B: public A 
{ 
    public: 
        void print () { std::cout<< "B::print()" << std::endl; } 
}; 

class C : public B 
{ 
    public: 
        void print () { std::cout<< "C::print()" << std::endl; } 
};
```

so, in my main I have declared base pointer `A*` bptr; later child's `B` and `C` also declared.

later bPtr pointed to `B` and called `print` function works as expected;
later bPtr pointed to `C` and called `print` function works as expected;

hear is code, no problems hear.

```
int main()  
{
    A* bPtr;

    B b;
    C c;

    bPtr = &b;
    bPtr->print(); // prints B::print() - as expected;

    bPtr = &c;
    bPtr->print(); // prints C::print() - as expected;

}
```

hear is my dilemma, I may understand wrong;
now what I thought all these days, `dynamic_cast` also does exactly above;
but things are different OR I am doing something wrong.

```
int main()
{

    A* bPtr = new C;

    bPtr = dynamic_cast<B*>( bPtr );

    bPtr->print(); // prints C::print() - expected B::print()

    /*
        I know above can be correct with explicit call
    */

    (dynamic_cast<B*>( bPtr ))->B::print(); // B::print


    bPtr = dynamic_cast<C*>( bPtr );

    bPtr->print(); // prints C::print()

    return 0; 


    if ( B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>( bPtr ))
    {
        b->print(); // still calls C::print() anyway;
    }

}
```

so hear is my question is `dynamic_cast` good for and only places like `if` statement to determine
the existence of inheritance between base and child's or safe cast between base and child's?

```
if ( B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>( bPtr ))
{
        b->print(); // still calls C::print() anyway;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour has nothing to do with dynamic_cast.

The behaviour of a virtual call will always depend on the actual runtime type of the value. In your second example, the only thing actually constructed is a `C`, so all calls will resolve to C, whether you call it an A: `A * a = bPtr` or a B: `B * b = bPtr`, it will resolve to C::print() because the statement `new C` constructs the actual value as a C.

Dynamic_cast is just going to cast the value given to the type specific, if it is (a subtype of) that type, or otherwise return `nullptr`. So dynamically casting a `B *` to `C *` will fail and return `nullptr`, but in your case you are casting `C *` to one of its base types, which will always succeed and never change the value itself.

Comment: looks like, I over think of subject, casting is not constructing an object.